# Cancellation in a sum of Möbius evaluated along a quadratic form

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x,y)$ be an indefinite binary quadratic form. Suppose $0 < B < \sqrt{A} $ are such that $B \gg \sqrt{A}$.

Is it true one can save an arbitrary power of log from the trivial bound in

$$\sum_{B \leq x \leq 2B \\  A \leq Q(x,y) \leq 2A} \mu (Q(x,y)) ?$$ In other words is it known that for any $C > 0$, $$\sum_{B \leq x \leq 2B \\  A \leq Q(x,y) \leq 2A} \mu (Q(x,y)) = O\left(\frac{B \sqrt{A}}{\log^C A}\right).$$

Any reference would be much appreciated :)

I am really interested when the addtional constraints $x \equiv u \pmod d$ and $y \equiv v \pmod d$ are imposed for some sufficiently small $d$.

Comment: There seem to be some misprints - $B<\sqrt A$ together with $B\gg\sqrt A$; also, what is $b$?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Thanks. The first thing is not a typo, I am using Vinogradov's asymptotic notation. So $B \gg \sqrt{A}$ means that there is a positive constant $c > 0$ such that $B \geq c \sqrt{A}$.